# How to make a node look differently in different views in OpenSceneGraph?

Tags: openscenegraph

What technique should be used in multi-view app (using CompositeViewer) if some nodes look differently in different views? For example, if some label positions should be recalculated depending on the view's camera parameters? Or if some other kind of annotations (rectangular area with a border some text) are visible or hidden depending on the view scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

osg has Billboard and Text classes that handle orientation for each camera out of the box (see for instance how the CullVisitor applies to the Billboard class [here](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/master/src/osgUtil/CullVisitor.cpp#L1061)).

To implement other behaviors which depend on the camera, the right place to make things happen is a Cull Callback added to your nodes: your callback will be invoked multiple times (one for each different camera) on every frame, and you can react accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to show/hide the node with this cull callback?

Comment: @Koban yes, you have several options (considering only those that respect the per-camera constraint), for instance: 1) return from the callback without traversing the children, which prevents child geometries to be rendered 2) use a different cull traversal mask for each camera and in your callbacks set/unset the matching bits on the node's nodemasks you want to be included or skipped for that camera.